# Magic keyboard problems when connected to iMac

Tags: macos, keyboard

When using my bluetooth Apple keyboard about 3 letters won't recognize on my iMac Desktop. When I type "K" for example I get nothing.

I know it's not the keyboard because I've connected it to my phone and all the numbers and letters work fine, it's only when I connect it to my computer that I have the problem.

When testing with a random keyboard all characters work just fine on my computer.

What else can I try to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out I had Mousekeys"Turned On" Feature activated.

Comment: That makes 9 keys inactive, 789uiojkl.  Odd it did not affect the random keyboard.